# Why does not pandas datetime work when trying to change dateformat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have the following code

```
temp1 = df.iloc[1:,0]
print(type(temp1))
temp2 = pd.to_datetime(temp1, format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

where df is a dataframe whose first column (i.e. column 0) contains dates with format "YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss". Now I'm trying to convert that into the format "YYYY-MM-DD" with line 2 and 3 but it does not anything to the format. The output is the following:
[image]

Can someone explain why my code does not work? When I try to print out the type of the two temporary variables, I get <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> for both.

Comment: `datetime` has no format, it's a binary value. If you want to display dates as strings in a certain way you need to format them explicitly with eg `strftime` or a format string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is to tell pandas how to parse the datetime string, not how to output the result. From the docs:

```
The strftime to parse time, e.g. "%d/%m/%Y"
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

You can use something like this to format the datetime:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['2012-01-01 12:00:01', '2012-01-01 12:00:02'])

pd.to_datetime(df[0]).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

0    01-01-2012
1    01-01-2012
Name: 0, dtype: object
```